# attach a table to a database from another database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm working on MSSQL 2008. And i want to insert a table that is already in db1, to another database db2. so i want to copy the table with attributes and content.
Can i do this?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the bare minimum table definition, without any constraints or indexes:

```
use db2
go

select * into dbo.NewTable from db1.dbo.OriginalTable
```